# java co-variance/contra-variance

Tags: java, inheritance, covariance, contravariance

Suppose I have:

```
class Event {}
class DoorBell extends Event {}
class PhoneCall extends Event {}
class EventGenerator {
    static Event getEvent() {
         if (today.isSunday())
            return new DoorBell()
         else 
            return new PhoneCall();
    }
}
class EventHandler {    
    void HandleEvent(DoorBell doorBell) { answer door; }
    void HandleEvent(PhoneCall phoneCall) { answer phone; }
    void consumeEvent() {
         Event e = EventGenerator.getEvent();
         HandleEvent(e);
    }
}
```

HandleEvent(e) doesn't compile since HandleEvent(Event) is undefined. Is there a solution for this? Or do I have to ask e what kind of event it is?

Comment: It seems, you're trying to reinvent algebraic datatypes and pattern-matching. Your "void HandleEvent"s are just static overloads, that are dispatched by static type information, so they don't fit. For the desired behaviour, you should ask the type of Event with "is", or use some heavy-weigh dispatch patterns like visitor. Also consider switching to Scala.

Comment: Sounds like work for a visitor pattern. I attempted to answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13150467/697630) recently perhaps it contains some interesting ideas, may not a answer, but worth considering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual idiom would be to pass an Event and let polymorphism handle it all for you.

I see no value in your `EventHandler` class without any behavior.  Your design, as posed, offers no polymorphic benefit.  That's the reason you have to check types.  Better to have something like this:

```
public interface EventHandler {
    void handle(Event event);
}
```

The [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) (aka "double dispatch") can be a good way to handle this situation.

Or you can try generics:

```
public class EventHandler {
   public <T> void consumeEvent(T event) {
       // handler code here, dependent on T
   }
}
```

I don't know if JDK 7 has something new to help you out.  Sorry; I'm still stuck on JDK 6.